# how can i see all contents of describe function in R

Tags: r, function, console, missing-data, describe

I used `describe` function in R for analyze big data. My bigdata has 74,836 obs & 147 variables.
And I input

```
describe(Data name)
```

But.. I can't see all contents in console page. only I can see about 90% data contents. this image is result. Many contents was cut.

[image]

how can I see all data set?? 
my code is very simple.

```
describe(welcomecredit)
```

`welcomecredit` is big data name.

Comment: You can assign it to an object and write the output to a file

Comment: I do not understand what is meant by "I can see about 90% data contents."

Comment: You've overflowed the console? I'd just call it on smaller subsets of your data. Really, if you've got results that big it's not all that human-readable, anyway.

Comment: @It means that every result was not displayed in console. Although I scrolled the bar, some data results was cut. help me....

Comment: Try to use `sink()` to pipe the output to a text file and open it then in an editor.

Comment: @If I have to use sink( ) , what instructions need? For example.. sink(file name? or describe(filename)?)